# Running bower install inside a docker volume

Tags: docker, polymer, bower

### Context

So I'm trying to execute build a polymer project inside a docker container as a volume (to access it I'm using `docker run (...) --volume="/var/www/html:/var/www/html" --volumes-from="my-polymer-image-name" my-nginx-image`).

And I tried execute the following Dockerfile, but declaring the volume last, but the volume was empty when I tried to access it from "my-nginx-container" (`docker exec -ti my-nginx-image-name /bin/sh`).

So I thought I had to declare the volume before using using it.

### Problem

But when I tried to install my bower components, I noticed that no `bower_components` directory was being created.

```
########################################################
# Dockerfile to build Polymer project and move to server
# Based on oficial node Dockerfile
########################################################
FROM node:6

VOLUME /var/www/html

# Install polymer and bower
RUN npm install -g \
    polymer-cli \
    bower

# Add project to a temp folder to build it
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/html/temp
COPY . /var/www/html/temp
WORKDIR /var/www/html/temp
RUN ls -la
RUN bower install --allow-root # here is where I try to build my project
RUN polymer build

# Move to release folder
WORKDIR /var/www/html
RUN mv /var/www/html/temp/build/unbundled/* /var/www/html
RUN bower install --allow-root

# Remove temporary content
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volume mount when docker image build done.

in last row in Docker file add

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/etc/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Use entripoint script like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e #if error bash script will exit and stop docker image
cd /var/www/html/
bower install --allow-root
polymer build
mv /var/www/html/temp/build/unbundled/* /var/www/html
rm -rf /var/www/html/temp
```